# set variable for number of lines in file

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract the number of lines in a file to a variable and then use this variable in the same script but it isn't working for me (the resulting file is empty but the code works if I hard code the number instead of the variable)
I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
mydir=`pwd`
echo $mydir
sample_info= sample.txt

NUMOFSAMPLES=$(wc -l $sample_info)

echo $NUMOFSAMPLES

## now apply my filter

awk '{if($8==0 && $10 == $NUMOFSAMPLES)print$0}' SJ.all > SJ.all.samples
```

Please help!

Comment: search for how to pass shell variables to `awk`.  Single quotes make the shell variables not visible within `awk`

Comment: Fixing the issues identified by http://shellcheck.net/ is a good place to start (emphasis on *start* -- one should typically begin there before asking questions here).

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is [not universally considered a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105); its behavior is [wildly incompatible between different shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/), and otherwise prone to lots of corner cases and gotchas. (If in a hurry, skip over the allegory in the link for the exercises below). `set -u` is much less fault-prone by comparison, but [nonetheless has drawbacks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112) as well.

Comment: what does the `echo $NUMOFSAMPLES` output. Ie is the value correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
sample_info="sample.txt"
num_of_samples=$(wc -l < "$sample_info")

awk -v num="$num_of_samples" '$8==0 && $10==num' SJ.all > SJ.all.samples
```

1. `var=value` is the correct syntax for variable assignment (no space before and after `=`)
2. Don't use uppercase variables as they could clash with environmental or internal shell variables
3. `wc -l < file` will not include the filename in the ouput
4. `awk -v var="$foo"` assigns value of shell variable `$foo` to `awk` variable `var`
5. `$8==0 && $10==num` if this condition is met, the default action, -- `print $0` -- is executed

Comment: Might also explicitly call out the removal of the unnecessary space that prevented the assignment to `sample_info` from working.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach using `sed`

```
sample_info=sample.txt
NumOfSamples=$(sed -n '$=' <"$sample_info")
# Note you shouldn't use full upper-case identifiers for user variables.
```

**What happens here**

---

- The `-n` option with `sed` suppresses default printing of each lines.
- The `$` looks for the last line in file and `=` prints the line number.

---

**Finally with awk, you can be more idiomatic**

```
awk -v n=$NumOfSamples '$8==0 && $10==n' SJ.all >SJ.all.samples
```

Comment: `"$sample_info"`, of course, to allow support for filenames with spaces. Might redirect -- `<"$sample_info"` to make names starting with dashes not be problematic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great suggestion, incorporated. :-). Regarding `to make names starting with dashes not be problematic.`  I was thinking if I should prefer `sed -n -- '$=' "$sample_info"` over `sed -n '$=' <"$sample_info"` though.

Comment: Either should do the trick -- I don't see a compelling reason to go one way or the other.